# Why does this compile normally with \def but hangs with \edef?

Tags: macros

Why does the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\CharBx{\textbf{\f@series}} 
\makeatother
\CharBx
\end{document}
```

compile normally (it returns 'bx'), while the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\edef\CharBx{\textbf{\f@series}} 
\makeatother
\CharBx
\end{document}
```

doesn't compile at all, but just hangs?

Comment: If I recall, `\textbf` is not expandable.   `\edef\CharBx{\noexpand\textbf{\f@series}}` but it gives the tokens `\textbf{m}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\textbf` (as many other commands in LaTeX is made robust using LaTeX's `\protect` system which you circumvent by manually using plain TeX's `\edef` instead of LaTeX's `\protected@edef`. With that your code works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\protected@edef\CharBx{\textbf{\f@series}} 
\makeatother
\CharBx
\end{document}
```

Of course this will show a bold `m` and not `bx` since `\f@series` gets expanded at the point of definition, while `\textbf` as a non-expandable command does not have any effect during the `\edef`.